# Alternative for scrolling on MacOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, macos

All Macs have this option to show scrollbars but it is turned off by default.

[image]

I was wondering if there is a way to show scrollbars even if this option is turned off?

Or is there some sort of alternative (JS/jQuery) that I could use that just puts in an arrow and triggers some sort of scrolling function?

Basically something that would work to scroll without technically having a scrollbar.

### Edit

As suggested I've started looking into the `scrollTop()` function in jQuery. Is there a way to get the `current_position` variable to get where the scrollbar should be?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // var current_position = $("#container").get_current_position();
  
  $("#up").bind("click", function(){
    $("#container").scrollTop(current_position - 100);
  });
  
  $("#down").bind("click", function(){
    $("#container").scrollTop(current_position + 100);
  });
  
});
```

```css
#container{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  padding:20px;
  background-color:#e33;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#inner{
  width:200px;
  height:1000px;
  background-color:#33e;
}
#up,#down{
  width:240px;
  height:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="up">
Up
</button>
<div id="container">
<div id="inner">

</div>
</div>
<button id="down">
Down
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are libraries (e.g. https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/iOS-Style-Custom-Browser-Scrollbar-with-jQuery-CSS.html) which add custom scrollbars to pages by js, but you should really question this idea since you are changing the default usability behavior of the browser.

If you just want a button to scroll you can easily implement this e.g. with jquery. See: https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/#scrollTop2

You can use scrollTop without parameter to get the current scroll position on the page, and if you need you can additional read out the pageheight ($(document).height();) and the viewport height ($(window).height();) in order to calculate the percentage of the page which is shown and where the actual position is relative to the content. See http://api.jquery.com/height/

Comment: Thanks I had tried that and it didn't work but I was missing the parseInt() function (see my answer below)

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing you can get to the scrollbars always being on is using CSS to style the scrollbar.

[It won't work in all browsers though](https://caniuse.com/#search=scrollbar)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, no matter what way you style your scrollbars they won't show on Mac (any browser) if that option is not turned on as far as I can tell

Comment: @PaddyHallihan See that's weird on my Mac it works and the "Automatically based on mouse or trackpad" option is selected, what version of OS X are you using it seems to be quite a old one looking at your screenshot.

Comment: I'm using Windows, my boss is the mac user. I grabbed that image off the web so probably not the same version. Not sure what version he's using. He wants it to be visible to everyone all the time no matter what options they have there.

Comment: @PaddyHallihan [These are some images of a permanent scrollbar using CSS](https://imgur.com/a/ck5a1Uq) I'm using Chrome 67 and macOS High Sierra. I know this works in OS X El Capitan as well. It won't matter what options the user has selected it's always there. Please could you share with me how you're implementing it and I'll be able to show you where you're going wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your advice but I've figured out an alternative that will work the way I want. See the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This code does what I want it to do now:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $("#up").bind("click", function(){
    var current_position = parseInt($("#container").scrollTop());
    $("#container").scrollTop(current_position - 100);
  });
  
  $("#down").bind("click", function(){
    var current_position = parseInt($("#container").scrollTop());
    $("#container").scrollTop(current_position + 100);
  });

});
```

```css
#container{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  padding:20px;
  background-color:#e33;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#inner{
  width:200px;
  height:1000px;
  background-color:#33e;
}
#up,#down{
  width:240px;
  height:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="up">
Up
</button>
<div id="container">
<div id="inner">

</div>
</div>
<button id="down">
Down
</button>
<br />
```